# What is a Rood Lebaxer?

Tags: meaning

I've been doing some geneaology and found an ancestor in the 1841 Scottish Census with an occupation of "Rood Lebaxer". This person lived in Southern Scotland so I'm guessing they would have been heavily influenced by English.

"Rood" can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_(unit)#In_Britain). It is a form of measurement in both English and Scots, but also could be used as a word for "pole". Assuming it is spelt correctly, I'm wondering what "Lebaxer" might mean.

Comment: A rood can also be a cross, as in [The Dream of the Rood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_of_the_Rood), a very old Christian poem in Old English.

Comment: I'm tempted to believe that it refers to a surveyor of some sort.

Comment: labach, labbich, llabbach are in the Scottish National Dictionary (https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/laib) but I can't find anything closer to Lebaxer. I could imagine a Scottish 'ch' being written as 'x(er)'. And Rood (https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/rude_adj_1) might mean 'inexperienced' (or worse!)

Comment: Lebaxer may be a mistranscription of laborer.

Comment: Are you working from a handwritten text like this? https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/files//images/portpatrick-wigtownshire-reference-1841-896-10-p16.jpg   A "rood labourer" would be an agricultural worker.

Comment: @TimR ... or "road labourer"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as TimR points out, censuses were written in longhand and the chances are that the OP has misread the word. This seems probable as, after 3 years, nobody has recognised the word "Lebaxter" and it appears in no dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

"Baxer" might be a variant of "Baxter" which means "Baker." Surnames of occupation often began with a 'le' meaning "the" as in "Giles le Baxter" meaning "Giles the Baker." These are medieval, and English, not Scottish, but might indiciatea line of inquiry. If cross-shaped loaves of bread, or "hot cross bun" style of loaves was something in Scotland before the time of the entry, then "rood the baker (of)" might be a formation. Merely conjectures and my source is Reaney, P.H. "A Dictionary of English Surnames" (OUP, 1997) with big arrow to "English."